# Dashcode and firefox compatibility

Tags: javascript, firefox, dashcode

I started to use [Dashcode](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html) with a Safari Custom Project, my apps work fine, but StackLayout Object does not work in Firefox.
I know Dashcode use many wekbit-specific things but is there any way I can get StackLayout object o work in Firefox? I would not mind losing some fancy stuff like transition-animations as long as my Views change.
StackLayout also does not work in IE, but I think that is too much to expect from IE. lol.

Any suggestions, ideas?
Maybe jQuery or Dojo libraries can be used with DashCode in case webkit is not available?. in this case how can I do this?

Thanks.

ADDED 2010/3/28:

This is my code:

```
function tab1ClickHandler(event){
    // introView tab
    var stackLayout = document.getElementById('stackLayout').object;
    stackLayout.setCurrentView('introView'); 

    var obj1= document.getElementById('text1');
    obj1.style.setProperty('background-image', 'url(Images/text3%201.png)', 'important');
    var obj2= document.getElementById('text2');
    obj2.style.setProperty('background-image', 'none', 'important');
    var obj3= document.getElementById('text3');
    obj3.style.setProperty('background-image', 'none', 'important');
}
```

I got the Stacklayout code from Dashcode inspector panel (So I don't think is incorrect)

Setting backgroung-image property is working well in FireFox. The problem is just Stacklayout's view change is not working.
You can see the results here:
http://web.me.com/nacho4d/
(Compare safari or chrome and firefox, click the tabs)

Any thoughts?
I asked the same question in dashboard-dev apple's mailing list but didn't get a reply yet.

Comment: do you have a URL or sample HTML code we could peek at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record:

It seems there is a bug (FireFox or Dashcode?) that won't let FireFox load the page correctly. I only tested with FireFox 3.6.2 (it was the latest that time)
The answer is here:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/dashboard-dev/2010/Mar/msg00017.html

Thanks.